# Install Mac-OS in Ubuntu server

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I maintain a remote `Ubuntu` server which I can access only through `SSH`. This server doesnt have any monitor, but have internet access. Within this Server, which runs `Ubuntu 18`, I also want to have `Mac-OS` which to be run in parallel.

Is there any way to make it possible?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: SO is only for programming questions, so server/OS support is off-topic. You could ask on [su], [sf], or [unix.se] instead.

Comment: The macOS license doesn't allow running it on non-Apple computers; unless your server is a Mac, this would be a license violation.